# PHP MYSQL if null statement

Tags: php, mysql

I need a way to do this, If a mysql query dosn't retrieve any data, something happens. Here's an example.

```
$color="red";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people WHERE shirt='$color'");
if($query = null){
echo 'No people wearing '.$color' shirts available.';
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `mysql_num_rows()` for this.

```
if( mysql_num_rows($query) == 0 ) {
    // No results returned
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`mysql_num_rows`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to check, how many rows have been returned by your query.

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");
mysql_select_db("database", $link);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table1", $link);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if( $num_rows == 0 ) {
    // No results returned
    echo "No results!";
} else {
    echo "$num_rows Rows\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the [`mysql_num_rows()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) there is also [`COUNT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) which could be used like this:

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM people WHERE shirt='$color'"
```

You might actually need more data from the database but if you only need a number then this would remove the need for an `if`.

Comment: A downside to this approach is that to actually get the data (if it exists) you have to make at least two calls to the database.  It's also possible that the data may change between the calls.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `empty` either:

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if(empty($num_rows)){
    echo 'No results';
}
```